# Primefaces wizard locale

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Following this:

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales

I could change Calendar component's locale.

But Wizard component's locale does not change next button's text.

Maybe should add a new key-value in js array but I don't know which key it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy, use:

```
nextLabel="Siguiente"
```

and

```
backLabel="Atrás"  (Atr&aacute;s)
```